# How to print the first node from a linked list of structs?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

Below is a Minimal Reproducible Example from my code. What I am doing is that I am inserting data in a list of structs and printing them on the console.

I want to print from each link only the first element that is inserted into each list of structs.

But how is that possible when instead of data in my struct I have:

```
typedef struct Node 
{
    int rollnumber, src, dst;
    double gentime;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;
```

(rollnumber, src, dst,gentime are the information I am reading from text files, but the reading code is not nessacary, so I wrote it with testdata.)

**MINIMAL REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE**

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

#define N   10

typedef struct Node
{
  int data;
  struct Node* next;
} Node;


int push_front(Node** head, int data)
{
  Node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  int success = new_node != NULL;

  if (success)
  {
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = *head;
    *head = new_node;
  }

  return success;
}

void output(Node* head)
{
  for (Node* current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next)
  {
    printf("%d ", current->data);
  }
}

void display(Node** set, int i)
{
    output(set[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
  int testdata = 1;
  Node* link[N] = { 0 };
  struct Node* head = NULL;

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    push_front(&link[i], testdata++);
    push_front(&link[i], testdata++);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    printf("link[%d]:", i);
    display(link, i);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the output you're getting vs. the output you desire ? The intent is somewhat confusing, so it may need a little rewording

Comment: @WhozCraig you are right, I am sorry.

Comment: No worries. `head` in `main` isn't even used in this code anyway, making its purpose as confusing now as its mis-definition *was*.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean `head` in `main` isn't used in the program. mis-declaring it is moot if it is just removed. Regarding my first question, however, what I mean is this: if answers start with "If i understand what you're asking..." chances are what you're asking isn't clear. If you clearly show what your expected vs. actual output is, it will probably bring clarity to your post, and I suggest you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70991181/edit) to provide that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to print the first element of each link list, just do not loop in `output`:

```
void output(Node* head)
{
    printf("%d ", head->data);
}
```

Comment: And what if data is a struct?

Comment: It prints segmentation fault.

Comment: The @Serge answer is right. If data is a **struct** you have to print **each single member** of the struct with `printf`. To access the member: `head->data.member`

Comment: And I do not have to change anything in the display function?

Answer (score 1):

If I am right you want the first element of the list right ??

If so than the way you are working you are pushing the new node in front of old node, so your first node is now the last in the line, so all you need to do is to iterate the list till Node* next == null, and that node will be your answer

```
Node *getLastInLine( Node *Head){
 Node *ptr;
 ptr = Head;
if( ptr == NULL) return NULL;
 while(ptr-> next != NULL){
  ptr = ptr->next;
 }
return ptr;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more? How do I call this function in the main?

Comment: you need to pass header in getLastInLine()
like if my header is by head
than 
getLastInLine(head) ;  // this will work